# Wordpress как отключить плагин из PHP?

Tags: wordpress

Как я могу выключить свой плагин из PHP?

Для отображения уведомлений там есть хук [admin-notices](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/admin_notices)

Но необходимо еще отключить его из плагинов.[image: 2] Как это сделать?

Comment: Что значит "выключить свой плагин из PHP"? Плагин сам себя должен отключать?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/deactivate_plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deactivate_plugins( $plugins, $silent, $network_wide );
```

- **$plugins(строка/массив)** (обязательный) - ID плагина или массив из ID. ID выглядит как путь до файла плагина относительно папки plugins
- **$silent(логический)** - Тихая деактивация. true - значит деактивировать плагин без включения событий деактивации (хуков deactivate_*).
  По умолчанию: false (хуки деактивации срабатывают)
- **$network_wide(логический/null)** - Деактивировать ли указанный плагины для всех сайтов сети (MU сборка). Значение null (по умолчанию) деактивирует плагины у текущего сайта и у сети.
  По умолчанию: null

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'action_deactivate_plugins' );
function action_deactivate_plugins(){
    deactivate_plugins( 'democracy-poll/democracy.php' );
}
```

[(источник)](https://wp-kama.ru/function/deactivate_plugins)